# Temporarily disable event listeners and rebind later

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, dom-events

I have a basic websocket program. I have a data callback where it analyzes the message and emits an event. Here is a minimal example showing everything that needs to be shown.

```
Cylon = new EventEmitter();

Cylon._createConnection = function(name) {
  let self = this;
  let socket = net.connect(this.config.port, this.config.host);

  socket.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
    let args = _.compact(data.toString('ascii').split(':'));
    args.push(name);
    self.emit.apply(self, args);
  }));

  return socket;
}

Cylon._commands = Cylon._createConnection('commands');

Cylon.on('TriggerActivated', (trigger) => {
  console.log(`Trigger warning! ${trigger}`);
});
```

Here is the problem: there exists an `echo` command that will simply relay the information as a string on the socket. Meaning the `Cylon.on('TriggerActivated')` could be tricked by doing `MG "TriggerActivated:test"`

So my question is: is there a way to temporarily unbind all event listeners?

```
Cylon._sendCommand = function (command) {
  check(command, String);
  if (command.splice(0,2) === 'MG') {
   // Unbind event listeners
   Cylon._commands.on('data', console.log);
   Cylon._commands.write(command);
   // Rebind all previous event listeners here
  }
}
```

Is this possible with JavaScript/node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (not tested):

```
// get current listeners
var listeners = Cylon.listeners(command)

// Unbind event listeners
Cylon.removeAllListeners(command);

// do your special processing
Cylon._commands.on('data', console.log);
Cylon._commands.write(command);

// Rebind all previous event listeners here
listeners.forEach(function(listener) {
    Cylon.on(command, listener);
};
```

But it's better to not emit the event at all:

```
  socket.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
    if (data.splice(0,2) !== 'MG') {
        let args = _.compact(data.toString('ascii').split(':'));
        args.push(name);
        self.emit.apply(self, args);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
  }));
```

Or something like this (emit a special event that you only subscribe to it).